# SQL 3 NF normalization

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

I have a table with 4 columns to display the bill of buying an item, column 1 is the primary key, column 2 and 3 are the price and the amount of the item, column 4 is the sum of the price, which is calculated by multiply the value in column 2 and 3. Do i need to delete column 4 to make sure that there is no transitive functional dependency in the table.

```
+---------+-------+--------+------+
| bill_id | price | amount | sum  |
+---------+-------+--------+------+
|       1 |     2 |      5 |   10 |
|       2 |     3 |      5 |   15 |
+---------+-------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Why would you, or wouldn't you? Where are you stuck in what process? PS The result of a multiplication is a product, not a sum.

Comment: Column 4 is dependent on column 2 and 3, which creates transitive dependency. I don't know if i should delete it or not to satisfy 3NF.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. And that is no explanation, it isn't reasoned by clear small steps back defintions. And it isn't transitive FDs that are a problem but certain transitive FDs. And you haven't said how you are stuck. Why don't you know? What step of reasoning are you stuck on? Otherwise we don't know what you do or don't understand or misunderstand & what are we supposed to answer? You would be just asking for a tutorial while pretending to have actually tried to answer by giving a guess at something you noticed.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need to. NFs are guidelines - very important and recommended, but just guidelines. While violation of 1NF is *almost* always a bad design decision, you may choose to violate 3NF and even 2NF provided you know what you are doing.

In this case, depending on the context, you may choose not to have a physycal "sum" column, and have the value calculated on the fly, although this could easily raise performance issues. But please don't even think of creating a new table which would have all possible combinations of quantity and unit price as a compound PK!

If you look at any ERP on the market you will see they store quantity, unit price, and total amount (and much more!) for every line of the quotes, orders, and invoices they handle.